# Angular templates - inject parameters

Tags: angularjs, templates

I am developing a lot of popups with the same set of buttons: Save, Apply, and Cancel. I am thinking to have a cached template that would hold these buttons. I am adding the template like this:

```
<ng-include src="'templates/popupButtonGroupTemplate.html'"></ng-
include>
```

And I am loading templates like this:

```
$http.get('templates/popupButtonGroupTemplate.html', {
    cache: $templateCache
});
```

That basically works. But now I need to manipulate these buttons. Specifically, set them to true or false depending on user changes into a form the template is added to. How can I have some code that would be included alone with a template every time a template is added to the form and how would I send a parameter to the code to specify a form name to use while watching for user changes?

Comment: what you are describing is a custom directive

Comment: I have added a custom directive: <ng-include popup-buttongroup form="caseBasicInfo" src="'templates/popupButtonGroup.html'"></ng-include> but it's not getting into it.

Comment: why are you combining it with `ng-include`?

Comment: Yes, my fault. I am going with a custom directive altogether.

Comment: But I am still facing a problem to send a form name into that custom directive to watch.